# Symfony2 - Session Name based on Route

Tags: php, symfony, session

I may going about this the wrong way but what I would like to do is change the session name based on the route that I have. I would like it to align exactly with the route prefix but, really, anyway to configure it will be fine.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
my_routes_1:
    resource: "@MyBundle1/Resources/config/routing.php"
    prefix:   /
    session:
        name: ROUTE1SESSID
my_routes_2:
    resource: "@MyBundle2/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /ab/
    session:
        name: ROUTE2SESSID
my_routes_3:
    resource: "@MyBundle3/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /cd/
    session:
        name: ROUTE3SESSID
```

But, obviously, that does not work. Do I really need to create something like a custom session storage or route loader or is there an easier way to accomplish what I want to do here?

Comment: Yeah if you want to do something the current class/lib does not do you need to override it with your own implementation (which could of course extend the existing stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You can use expressions in your routing to add conditions. The request is available in the routing expression so you should be able to check in that.</s>

```
my_routes_1:
    resource: "@MyBundle1/Resources/config/routing.php"
    prefix:   /
    condition: "request.hasSession() && 'ROUTE1SESSID' === request.getSession().getName()"

my_routes_2:
    resource: "@MyBundle2/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /ab/
    condition: "request.hasSession() && 'ROUTE2SESSID' === request.getSession().getName()"

my_routes_3:
    resource: "@MyBundle3/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /cd/
    condition: "request.hasSession() && 'ROUTE3SESSID' === request.getSession().getName()"'
```

**Sorry, that was nothing to do with the question**

From looking through the code and from the fact you said there were issues with setting the session name after it has been activated, it seems the only way to manage this would be to set the name before it is activated.

To do this you could create a listener that is loaded `onKernelRequest` before anything else and manage the session name from there. From what I can see the session isn't created until it is first requested in the token storage, so essentially if you get in before the security context does any of the `[get|set|has|remove]Token()` stuff then you should be alright.

*Please note that I haven't tested this in any way*

<kbd>AppBundle\Event\SessionNameSubscriber</kbd>

```
class SessionNameSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $routeSessionNames = array(
        'my_routes_1' => 'ROUTE1SESSID',
        'my_routes_2' => 'ROUTE2SESSID',
        'my_routes_3' => 'ROUTE3SESSID',
    );

    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session = null)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // If no session is loaded do not set name.. obviously
        if (null === $this->session) {
            return;
        }

        $currentRoute = $request->attributes->get('_route');

        foreach ($this->routeSessionNames as $route => $sessionName) {
            if (strpos($currentRoute, $route) === 0) {
                $this->session->setName($sessionName);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array('onKernelRequest', 2048)
        );
    }
}
```

<kbd>AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml</kbd>

```
app.subscriber.set_session_name:
    class: AppBundle\Event\SessionNameSubscriber\SessionNameSubscriber
    arguments:
        - "@?session"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: I'm looking for more of a way to set the session name, not check it. I tried something similar to this with condition: `"request.hasSession() &&  (request.getSession().setName('ROUTE3SESSID') || true)"'` but symfony doesn't like it when you try to change the name of an active session

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed. I added a route option to the routes that I wanted and included the router and used that to match/verify the route from the request directly but, other than that, I don't think I changed much